# Transfer Function for Electro-Mechanical System

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, transfer-function, systems-engineering

[image: Electro-Mechanical Schematic]

Can anyone please lead me in the right direction as to how to solve for the transfer function given this motor schematic

Comment: i guess es is the input, L and C are energy storage elements.  what are alpha and J (and 2 wires? connecting them?) supposed to be?  D looks almost like a wall to have J apply forces to?

Comment: I think J would be moment of inertia, D an external load or disturbance torque, and alpha would, I think, be a torque constant, relating torque to current

Comment: Where did you find this diagram and what have you tried so far? Have you already setup the (differential) equations for the electrical circuit part and the mechanical part separately? If so, please add those to the question using the [edit] option below the question.